# Is there the way to programmatically change Windows Server password ignoring Local Password Policy using Admin account?

Tags: c++, .net, winapi, server-administration

I have Admin account and want to change password for a specific user on a local Windows Server 2008 machine. Is there possibility to programmatically change the password ignoring Local Password Policy (complexity, history, minimum password age)?

I tried NetUserChnagePassword but it does not allow to ignore Password Policy.

Comment: From a security perspective I hope there is not.